# Instantiating various inherited classes through one method, without reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, polymorphism, abstract-class

In a project I'm working on, I have a set of blocks that make up a 3D voxel based environment (like Minecraft). These worlds are stored in an external data file.

This file contains the data for:
Each block,
its location,
and its type.

When the LoadLevel method is called, I want it to iterate over the data for every block in the file, creating a new instance of the Block object for every one. It's no problem to pass things like location. It's as simple as

```
CreateBlock(Vector3 position)
```

The issue is with the type. All types are child classes (think Abstract Block, and then subtypes like GrassBlock or WaterBlock that inherit the abstract Block's properties.) Assuming there's a child class like "GrassBlock" that I want to be created, rather than a generic block, how do I make it do this through the method? The only way I know of is through reflection, which I've been advised to stay away from. Is it possible that I can do this through generic typing or something?

This seems like such an important question in game design, but no one I've asked seems to have any idea. Any help?

Comment: If you're creating your blockds at load-time, reflection could be a viable option. `Activator.CreateInstance` is reasonably fast.

Comment: My comment is that in essence you are talking about run time creation of a type, without knowing in advance which type.  There are only two ways to accomplish this 1) You must know the type via the Type.Name or 2) You must have a string value indicating the type.  The two answers below are right on target.  Notice the first indicates you must pass in the type, the next answer says you must use reflection (which allows you to use strings to determine things).

Comment: You may want to consider whether class inheritance is really appropriate in this case. If you use *composition* instead of inheritance, then each block is just a `Block`, with a `BlockType` (enum) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic typing will still require reflection.

First of all: what you're looking for is the *factory pattern*. It creates objects for you without having to do it explicitly yourself everywhere.

Basically there are two options:

- **Reflection**

This indeed has a performance impact connected to it but don't dismiss it if you haven't determined it to be a problem yet. It will be readable and maintainable.

- **Switches**

Hardcode every option and create a new instance based on some sort of metadata you pass in (something that will identify the type of each block). This has the benefit of not using reflection and as such not incurring that performance penalty but it will also be less extensible and if you have 500 different blocks you can guess what your code will look like.

Comment: Thank you for this really nice explanation. I think I will go with reflection after all, as it's only being run during the loading phase, when performance isn't a super huge issue. I would have used a switch, but I intend the code to be easy to tinker with in case modders want to add their own block types. Reflection seems key, as a switch would require more coding for them to get their block types to work.

Answer (score 1):

Without reflection, you can use a factory method, with a `switch`. Assume `BlockType` is an enum.

```
public static Block CreateBlock(BlockType type, Vector3 position)
{
    switch (BlockType type)
    {
    case BlockType.Grass:
        return new GrassBlock(position);
    case BlockType.Water:
        return new WaterBlock(position);
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

But to have something more maintainable, you could still use reflection until it proves to be a bottleneck. In that case, you could switch to *runtime code generation*.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<Vector3, Block>> _activators = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Vector3, Block>>();

public static Block CreateBlock(Type blockType, Vector3 position)
{
    Func<Vector3, Block> factory;

    if (!_activators.TryGetValue(blockType, out factory))
    {
        if (!typeof(Block).IsAssignableFrom(blockType))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var posParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Vector3));
        factory = Expression.Lambda<Func<Vector3, Block>>(
            Expression.New(
                blockType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Vector3) }),
                new[] { posParam }
            ),
            posParam
        ).Compile();

        _activators.Add(blockType, factory);
    }

    return factory(position);
}
```

This code will generate a factory function at runtime, the first time a block of a given type is requested. And you could make this function thread-safe if needed by using a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

But that *may* be a bit overkill for your purpose ;)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can create objects without any reflection.
Simple assign each class the integer index:

```
Func<Vector3, Block>[] factories =
{
    (v) => new GrassBlock(v),    // index 0
    (v) => new WaterBlock(v),    // index 1
    . . .
}
```

Save this index in the external data. At deserialization time read Vector3 `v` and index `i`, then call `var block = factories[i](v);`

Comment: What advantage does this give over a `switch` statement?

Comment: It depends. My opinion, this decision is shorter, potentially faster, and more extensible.

Comment: Shorter? If you mean "fewer characters", yeah. Faster? Highly unlikely. More extensible? Probably not as written (using a static array). And using magic integers as indexes seems really difficult to maintain.

Comment: Faster cause array gives O(1) instead of O(N) for `switch`. Of course, it does not matter if N < 10, but if N = 30, then array will be faster.

Extensible, cause we can use hashes instead of arrays, if we need. This can be useful in a team (for multiple programmers).

Finally, I don't think that the code

    case AAA: return new AAAClass();
    case BBB: return new BBBClass();

increases the clarity and simplifies the maintain.

Comment: You're making assumptions about how `switch` is implemented. The compiler is typically smart enough to choose between if/else blocks, jump tables, or hashtables based on the case statements. It can do this because all the values are constant and known at compile-time. If you want better extensibility/maintainability, there *are ways* to achieve it using hashtables. I'm not saying switch statements are necessarily the best option. But if you have a code block that declares all the values like this, then magic number indices just make things more fragile with no advantage that I can see.

Comment: My opinion, there is not magic numbers in this pattern. Classes' names shows what you want. Enums just duplicate them, and doesn't give useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you avoiding reflection? If you're able to execute this code only on startup (which it sounds like you can do if you're reading a file) then I don't personally have too big a problem with using reflection.

An alternative is to store the fully qualified type name (e.g. My.System.Blocks.GrassBlock) and load that type with

```
var typeName = readStringTypeFromFile(file);
Block type = Activator.CreateInstance(typeName, location);
```

As I said, running something like this on startup is fine by me, and you can test performance of this if needs be.

Quick and dirty fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BDmlyi

Comment: No particular reason otherwise than I wasn't sure if it was a wise choice. But yes, it will only be running that code on load time so it seems okay in the end. I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!